# js functions getting appended into input tag

Tags: javascript, events

I am facing weird problem which i couldnt figure out.

in internet explorer,

```
<input name="name" class="autocomplete" id="handle" type="text" previous="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" next="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" selectionhandler="TravellerAutocomplete" idfield="name" queryurl="http://localhost/javascripts/peopledata.json" getElementsByClassName="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" fire="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" observe="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" stopObserving="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" visible="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" toggle="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" hide="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" show="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" remove="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" update="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" replace="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" insert="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" wrap="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" inspect="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" recursivelyCollect="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" ancestors="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" descendants="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" firstDescendant="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" immediateDescendants="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" previousSiblings="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" nextSiblings="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" siblings="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" match="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" up="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" down="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" adjacent="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" identify="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" readAttribute="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" writeAttribute="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" getHeight="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" getWidth="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" classNames="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" hasClassName="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" addClassName="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" removeClassName="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" toggleClassName="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" cleanWhitespace="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" empty="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" descendantOf="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" scrollTo="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" getStyle="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" getOpacity="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" setStyle="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" setOpacity="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" getDimensions="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" makePositioned="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" undoPositioned="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" makeClipping="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" undoClipping="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" cumulativeOffset="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" positionedOffset="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" absolutize="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" relativize="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" cumulativeScrollOffset="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" getOffsetParent="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" viewportOffset=""/>
```

displaying like above if i inspect the element. thats why selectionhandler function is not at all working with this input tag.

In other page if i add any input tag, its working properly, i,e. js code is not appending.

is there something which i am missing?

selectionhandler function is like this :

```
function TravellerAutocomplete (){ alert("hi"); }
```

Comment: You need to give some background about your problem, have you written some javascript? why version of IE? what's happening in other browsers?

Comment: @badZoke in all other browsers its working fine. and i have a selectionhandler function, which is working fine. IE all versions its not working.

Comment: have you written the `selectionhandler()`, please post that as well

Comment: @badZoke i hav updated the question with selectionhandler().

Comment: Please post the entire snippet, how are you calling the function on the input element etc..